# Left string limit repl.bat output

Tags: batch-file

Trying to limit the output of this script to 25 characters for the information for Name=$1 output.

Thanks

David

```
@echo off
set "input=before.txt"
set "output=after.txt"
findstr /r /i /c:"^Job Notes=" "%input%" |repl ".*=(.*) (\d+) (\d+\/\d+\/\d+) \d+:\d+:\d+ .*" "Name=$1\r\nFile Number=$2\r\nDate=$3" x >"%output%"
findstr /r /i /c:"^File Type=" "%input%" >>"%output%"
findstr /r /i /c:"^Location="  "%input%" >>"%output%"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
".*=(.{0,25}).* (\d+) (\d+\/\d+\/\d+) \d+:\d+:\d+ .*"
```

Limit what you are retrieving inside $1 and move the discarded part out of the capture